# String - Varchar - SQLite datatypes

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, varchar

In SQLite, String - varchar can anyone tell the exact difference between both of this?

Comment: in sqlite v3 datatype `text` act for these 2 types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html); the name of the declared data type does not matter:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    Col1 TEXT,           -- this is stored as a text value
    Col2 STRING,         -- so is this
    Col3 VARCHAR(1),     -- and this
    Col4 FLUFFY BUNNIES, -- and this
    Col5,                -- and this
    Col6 INTEGER         -- and this, if the actual value is not a number
);
```

The declared length is ignored, too (it's used only by the query planner to estimate the amount of I/O).

To enforce data types or lengths, you would need a separate CHECK constraint:.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    Col7 TEXT NOT NULL  CHECK(typeof(Col7) = 'text')
);
```

Comment: The single most critical data type in all my projects is `FluffyBunnies`.

Comment: STRING doesnot restrict size?, VARCHAR is allow to restrict size? is this correct?

Comment: No, that's not what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

All string datatypes in SQLite are converted to a TEXT datatype unless you're using a BLOB, because SQLite does not allow size restrictions on string datatypes.